# Eloquent model considered 'dirty' despite no underlying values have changed due to encrypted values

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, eloquent

Is there a way to prevent an eloquent model from being considered 'dirty' using the `$model->isDirty()` function when calling `$model->save()` due to a few of the attributes being encrypted.

Certain model properties have their accessors overridden to encrypt and decrypt their values. So if we're updating a model via a form on the front end but none of the unencrypted data has changed, it still causes the model to become dirty and update the `updated_at` timestamp.

The initial "simple" way I can think of would be applying this kind of logic to everywhere we update models.

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user) 
{
    if ($user->name !== $request->input('name')) {
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
    }

    ...

    $user->save();
}
```

Can anyone think of a quicker/cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe use [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events) and centralize that logic on the `Updating` event. Just an idea.

Comment: How are you handling encryption now?